# WCF trace logs all exceptions except System.Exception itself

Tags: wcf

I've made a basic WCF Service Library and created one method called `GetResult()`. I've set up WCF trace logging to log Warnings to a file.  This is correctly logging all exceptions thrown **except**, for some strange reason, `System.Exception` itself.  For instance, this logs fine:

```
[OperationContract]
public string GetResult()
{
    // exception is logged in file:
    throw new DivideByZeroException();
    // or
    // throw new ApplicationException();
    // or
    // throw new FileNotFoundException();
    // or anything else, it seems
}
```

But this does not log anything:

```
[OperationContract]
public string GetResult()
{
    // exception is not logged!
    throw new Exception();
    // or
    // throw new Exception("my message");
}
```

In the latter case, the log file doesn't even get created.  If it already exists then it doesn't get written to.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Here is my app.config setup:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning">
            <listeners>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning">
            <listeners>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization" switchValue="Warning">
            <listeners>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
<trace autoflush="true" />
    <sharedListeners>
        <add initializeData="c:\temp\logs\wcf.svclog" 
       type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
       name="ServiceModelTraceListener" 
       traceOutputOptions="Timestamp" />
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Are you sure your throw exception code is even being hit?

Comment: @MikeChamberlain did you find resolution of this problem? I am trying to log all exceptions in my console app but could not make it work.